# Python - how to save a data frame (or variable) for use and manipulation in a different module (file) without global variables

Tags: python, pandas, global-variables

I have a project with a bunch of python files (modules) that do different stuff. I keep those files in a folder called "modules". One thing I do in the project is to create a pandas data frame from an excel-file. I then read and/or modify this df in the modules.

What I do so far is to write the df in a global variable in a separate file:

```
-> modules/global_variables.py

import pandas as pd

df: pd.DataFrame = None
(...some other global variables...)


---------------------------

-> excel.py:

import pandas as pd
import modules.global_variables as gv

def import_xl(file) -> None:

    df = pd.read_excel("path/file.xlsx")
    (...some initial cleaning of the df...)

    gv.df = df.copy()
```

Now I have the data frame saved as a global variable and can access it from any other module by importing the global variables file without having to import the excel-file again (which takes a lot of time). I do the same for other variables (dicts, lists, etc.) that I need in various modules.

I read this is a bad way to do it because it uses global variables. I however don't understand how to do this without them...

Can you help?

Comment: Hi, you could make a package of `modules` by creating an __init__.py file in it, and in this file, add `df = pd.read_excel("path/file.xlsx")`. Then, when importing the dataframe in your main module (where all other modules are called, I presume) by calling `from modules import df`, `df` will be instantiated once and only once, and then be available for the rest of the runtime.

Comment: Hi @Laurent, thank you very much for your reply. This is interesting - I never thought to put stuff in the init.py-file. However, wouldn't this be the same issue (using a global variable) just in a different file?

Comment: Most probably, yes. I was rather pointing out a possibly more idiomatic way to do it. Global variables are not bad per se, but they can be a problem if your code mutates them (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22797101/11246056). Perhaps you should consider another approach: instantiate the dataframe once, and refactor, if need be, your functions or methods so that they take a dataframe as an argument and always return a new one (thus passing, at runtime, the modified dataframe from one function to the next).

Comment: So it's ok to save the df in a global variable as long as I make sure it doesn't get changed by any function in my code... in essence making it a "global constant". Any modification to that df should then be saved in a new variable.  Did I get that right?